# Unity light baking - How to manage mixed lighting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a pretty large scene, where I have 1 directional light (sun) set to mixed.
I mainly used realtime lighting during development in order to save time.
Now before release I want to bake, to improve performance for my users.

My questions are

- Is there any rule of thumb for any of the values in light-settings?
- which objects should I set to static (I set everything that doesnt move to static) and is something wrong if my bake takes 3-4 hours?
- Should I use realtime GI since I have mixed lighting, or is Baked GI enough?

I use fairly high settings for my final bake because I want it to looks nice, and I bake everything that doesnt move in the scene (thousands of objects). While it does take hours, the light map size ends up at around 60mb after compression, which doesnt seem bad.

My settings are like the image below, except I've increased:

Direct samples: 200

Indirect samples: 1000

Resolution: 24

Parameters: Default High

The reason for increasing these values is simply because my objects did not look good in a bake with any lower settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to bake, to improve performance

**Notes:**

- Baking usually improves visuals.
- But this creates a lot of textures, so it may lower performance.
- Using ONLY the baked lights, it's basically unlit - very good performance.
- Mixed means you bake the indirect lights (because without realtime raytracing you won't have indirect lighting*) and still use realtime lights for some things like hard shadows.
- If you don't want to rotate the directional light (sun) or move point lights around, there is no use in baking the realtime GI.

[*] : We can fake some realtime GI / soft indirect lighting by pre-baking this. So "Realtime GI" allows you to rotate the Directional Light (Sun) or even move lights around, but not objects. And you need to bake it, usually including some light-probes. So "realtime" doesn't mean it's bake-less. And it's not the same as real raytracing.

**Duration:**

Using 2018.3 or 2019.1 (not sure) you can try the GPU Lightmapper (preview) - it is a lot faster. However using CPU 3-4 hours is quite normal to me.

**Static?**

Marking things as static is always good for performance, but you can also mark non-static things as "Lightmap-static" if you want movable houses to be pre-baked for example.

**Lightmap Debug Mode:**

> The reason for increasing these values is simply because my objects did not look good

In Scene view, you can select a "Lightmap" mode (not sure how it's called).
It displays basic chess/checker texture on all objects with lightmap-UVs. Use this view to scale lightmap UVs to increase details on close objects for example.

---

*edit:*

**Mixed Lighting - Performance?**

This will bake the light for all static (or at least lightmap-static) objects in the scene. During runtime, lighting is not computed for the static ones anymore.

At least that's what the [Manual](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/choosing-lighting-technique) says:

> Selecting the ‘Mixed’ baking mode, GameObjects marked as static will still include this light in their Baked GI lightmaps. However, unlike lights marked as ‘Baked’, Mixed lights will still contribute realtime, direct light to non-static GameObjects within your scene.

I just tested:

"Baked" - After Baking, rotating the sun didn't affect the scene until rebake.

"Mixed" - I can rotate the sun and affect shadows. Note: "static" objects still get some indirect light (reflecting from the surroundings) while non-static objects are not baked, and therefore completely black on the side which is not facing the sun.

The Lighting tab says

> Mixed lights provide realtime direct lighting. Indirect lighting gets baked into lightmaps and light probes. [...]

**Performance:**

This is hard to answer without a test, as I am only relying on theoretical facts, and maybe assumptions.

I would say the Mixed Light mode is just to have better visuals (indirect lighting). This is precomputed, but the textures still need to be multiplied/added to the pixel lighting in the shader - this costs a bit performance.

**And the direct light is still computed in realtime - so if I understood the docs correctly, Mixed is always worse than only realtime lighting in terms of performance.**

But: If your sun doesn't even move - you can use it in "baked" mode instead of "mixed" - this will bake shadows to texture and save the calculation at runtime. This is the only option that **for sure** is better in performance. I'm not 100% sure about the mixed mode.

And realtime lights will still affect them. A torch for example.

However your non-static player will not get the sunlight lighting/shadow because it cannot be baked. You could try using an unlit shader on him, and add a fake shadow under it. Or you place a point light above it to fake the sun.

Comment: Thanks first of all! Does it really lower performance? I've read that the cost of using realtime lights for a scene is quite high for the end-user since it needs so many calculations and draw-calls? 
If this isnt true then I won't bake anything and just stick with realtime lighting for my entire scene, since my visuals stay the exact same.

Comment: Well the textures "consume" or occupy memory. They need to be loaded and fed to the shader. This is probably very low impact. But compared to non-baked it is a difference of course. Talking about "Mixed" here. If you bake and then remove/deactivate the sun, or just use the "baked" setting instead of "mixed" it will completely save you the lighting cost. With a single directional light it's fine, but having 10 lights will impact performance (draw calls/batches) a lot more, especially on forward rendering path.

Comment: Thanks again. I used deferred lighting, I have not messed with those settings since I do not fully understand them. I have a single directional, with 90% of my objects marked as static since my sun does not move. So I think in my scenario performance should improve quite a bit compared to not baking lights for all these objects, correct? I mean the lightmaps end up at around 50-80mb, not really that heavy. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Using the sun in "baked" mode - yes I would totally expect it. But you should also look into the Profiler and the Frame Debugger. Both are quite easy and can help you improve performance. There is also a Scene view called "overdraw" or simliar. Very nice to debug transparent stuff.

Comment: btw, my sun is in Mixed mode, I only have one directional light (sun) and its mixed. This has to improve performance if I use baked GI right? I mean you remove a ton of calculations that realtime would have to do, and instead store them as textures, or did I misunderstand? I can't imagine realtime lighting being more performant friendly, seems really backwards.

Comment: I'm afraid mixed is not better than "realtime". I've added a detailed explanation under the horizontal line and the "edit:" called "Mixed Lighting - Performance?" - I didn't compare performance myself, this is only my understanding of the docs and my experience. I may still be wrong but maybe my explanations help you with your problem. In the end I'd be happy if you just did a comparison to clear this fog of assumptions. Build realtime & mixed and compare fps. Would be nice if you share.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great explenations man, it really helped me :)

Comment: For future readers, I found this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeLightingPipelines.html , its an amazing source